# Is there a standard notation for the plane passing through three non-collinear points?

Tags: geometry, notation, axiomatic-geometry

Is there a "standard" notation for designating the unique plane passing through given three non-collinear points $A$, $B$, and $C$? Lacking a standard notation, are there notations used for this purpose in some popular maths textbooks/papers or in some textbooks/papers written by distinguished mathematicians?

For comparison, $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ is [a standard notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line.html) for the unique line passing through the distinct points $A$ and $B$.

---

I'll repeat what I wrote [in a comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472214/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-the-plane-passing-through-three-non-collinear-p/4472387#comment9374132_4472214): I am interested in a notation that is viable in a Synthetic Geometry framework, where there's no coordinate system. Of course, there's nothing in my original question to indicate there's a coordinate system that can be used, so this remark is just for emphasis.

Comment: "Standard" is a dangerous word, for instance I have never seen this notation for a line you are proposing. I would call if $\mathrm{aff}(A,B)$, $\mathrm{aff}(A,B,C)$ and so on, where aff stands for affine hull. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek $\operatorname{aff}(A,B,C)$ has an Analytic Geometry or Linear Algebra feel to it. I wonder if there is a neutral notation for a plane that is used even in the absence of a coordinate system, as when discussing Synthetic Geometry.

Comment: It's not-unreasonable to denote the line through $A$ and $B$ as "line $AB$" (and thereafter simply "$AB$"). The same goes for planes: introduce "plane $ABC$" and then just use "$ABC$".

Comment: @Blue $AB$ can mean the line passing through $A$ and $B$, the line segment between $A$ and $B$, the ray from $A$ to $B$, the circle about $A$ passing through $B$. Similarly, $ABC$ could have several conflicting meanings. Yes, you could always write "the plane $ABC$" just as you could always write "one hundred and thirty five", but "135" is nevertheless quite convenient.

Comment: @EvanAad: Yes, "$AB$" can have many meanings. *In context*, there may be no danger of conflict, as an author can specify which meaning is intended. Also, the author can simply not drop the descriptor word; ie, *always* write "line $AB$" and "segment $AB$". (When typesetting of over-bars and -arrows is unavailable/undesirable, such a fallback is needed.) ... I'm reminded of Lewis Carroll's incarnation of Humpty-Dumpty, who said, "When *I* use a word [or in this case, a symbol], it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."

Comment: @Blue Be that as it may, this is irrelevant to the question I asked. I did not ask: how could I notate the plane through the points $A$, $B$, and $C$. I asked whether there is a standard notation for such a plane, or, lacking a standard notation, if there is... But I repeat myself. I refer you to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

No; the closest I've seen is "Plane defined by $ABC$" or "Plane defined by $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}$" or "Plane defined by points $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{C}$".

Furthermore, I claim that it is better to use a simple, consistent notation, and *describe* it at the first use, than try to relying on "commonly recognized notation".  This is because in various subfields from pure linear algebra to physics, very different notation is "standard" anyway; but in all subfields, the best articles **always** describe the notation (and abbreviations) at first use.

---

OP is not interested in any suggestions, but personally, I would use something like

> Plane $ABC$ is the plane passing through three non-collinear points $A$, $B$, and $C$; the locus of points $P$ such that $P \cdot\left(\overline{AB}\times\overline{AC}\right) - A \cdot \left(\overline{AB}\times\overline{AC}\right) = 0$.

for the first instance, and then just "plane $ABC$" afterwards, assuming notation $\overline{AB} = B - A$ is acceptable; otherwise,

> Plane $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}$ is the plane passing through three non-collinear points $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, and $\mathbf{C}$; that is, the locus of points $\mathbf{P}$ such that $\mathbf{P} \cdot \bigl(\left(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{A}\right) \times \left(\mathbf{C}-\mathbf{A}\right)\bigr) - \mathbf{A} \cdot \bigl(\left(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{A}\right) \times \left(\mathbf{C}-\mathbf{A}\right)\bigr) = 0$.

Note that the above is equivalent to $\left(\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{A}\right) \cdot \left(\mathbf{B} - \mathbf{A}\right) \times \left(\mathbf{C} - \mathbf{A}\right) = 0$, a triple product, but this form is not as recognizable as the standard implicit definition of a plane in vector notation.  Thus, I would advise against using this form even if it is more elegant.

For those who are not aware of it, the plane normal $\mathbf{N}$ is obtained by the cross product of any pair of edges between the three points, and the signed distance $d$ (in units of the plane normal length) is the dot product between the plane normal and any of the three points (all three yield the same distance $d$).  These are then used in the implicit equation of the plane: the locus of points $\mathbf{P}$ where $\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{N} - d = 0$.